# Unable to insert data including a timestamp with the PG gem?

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I am using the PG gem to insert data into my Postgres database, however, when I try to insert data including a timestamp, the database does not get updated. Here is the code I ran from IRB:

```
 :001 > require 'pg'
 => true 
 :002 > conn = PGconn.open(:dbname => 'my_db')
 => #<PG::Connection:0x8fa4a94 @socket_io=nil, @notice_receiver=nil, @notice_processor=nil>  
 :003 >   conn.prepare('statement1', 'insert into sites (url, note, type, last_viewed) values ($1, $2, $3, $4)')
 => #<PG::Result:0x8f3c19c @connection=#<PG::Connection:0x8fa4a94 @socket_io=nil, @notice_receiver=nil, @notice_processor=nil>> 
 :004 >   conn.exec_prepared('statement1', [ 'digg.com', 'news site', 3, date_trunc('second', #{conn.escape_string(current_timestamp)) ] )
 :005 >
```

I believe the issue is related to the way in which the single quotes are escaped. I started including the PG gem's `escape_string` method because of the error message I received when I ran my previous version of the code on line 4.

```
004 >   conn.exec_prepared('statement1', [ 'digg.com', 'news site', 3, date_trunc('second', current_timestamp) ] )
NameError: undefined local variable or method `current_timestamp' for main:Object
from (irb):4
from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I'd highly recommend looking at the [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/index.html) gem. It's a very well written ORM that lets you talk to a database in a DBM agnostic manner, without worrying about flavors of SQL. Look through the [Readme](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/README_rdoc.html) to get a good idea what it can do. The author is a big fan of PostgreSQL so Sequel definitely works with it.

Comment: @theTinMan I'll definitely check it out, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you mixing Ruby and SQL strangely; for example, `current_timestamp` is SQL but `conn.escape_string` is Ruby. In this case I'd just inline the SQL in your prepared statement:

```
conn.prepare(
  'statement1',
  %q{
    insert into sites (url, note, type, last_viewed)
    values ($1, $2, $3, date_trunc('second', current_timestamp))
  }
)
```

That's perfectly safe to do as you're not interpolating anything into the SQL, you're just tossing bit more SQL into your INSERT.